# UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() stops without reason

Tags: c#, oracle

I have this piece of C# code to update an Oracle Table.
The moment `oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`is executed, everything stops. No exception, nothing! It doesn't even go to `finally`.
What could be the issue?

```
    OracleTransaction oracleTransaction = null;
    OracleConnection oracleConnection = null;
    OracleDataAdapter oracleDataAdapter = null;
    OracleCredential oracleCredential = new OracleCredential((string)args["Username"], (SecureString)args["SecurePassword"]);
    string CustomerID = (string)args["CustomerID"];
    string FromUserID = (string)args["FromUserID"];
    XElement ToUserIDsElement = (XElement)args["ToUserIDsElement"];

    try
    {
        using (oracleConnection = new OracleConnection((string)args["OracleConnectionString"], oracleCredential))
        {
            oracleConnection.Open();
            using (oracleTransaction = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
            {
                string commandText = @"
                                MERGE INTO T_USER_AUTHORIZATION_BASE TGT
                                USING (
                                    SELECT  C.CUSTOMER_NAME
                                        ,   U1.USER_NAME AS U1_USER_NAME
                                        ,   UA1.USER_ID AS UA1_USER_ID
                                        ,   UA1.CUSTOMER_ID AS UA1_CUSTOMER_ID
                                        ,   UA1.ENTITY AS UA1_ENTITY
                                        ,   UA1.SIGNATURE_LEVEL AS UA1_SIGNATURE_LEVEL
                                        ,   UA1.INQUIRY AS UA1_INQUIRY
                                        ,   UA1.TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION AS UA1_TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION
                                        ,   UA1.IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS AS UA1_IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                        ,   UA1.IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS AS UA1_IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                        ,   UA1.CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR AS UA1_CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR
                                        ,   UA1.IS_AUDIT AS UA1_IS_AUDIT
                                        ,   UA1.INTERNAL_LIMIT AS UA1_INTERNAL_LIMIT
                                        ,   UA1.PURGE AS UA1_PURGE
                                        ,   UA1.STATIC_DATA AS UA1_STATIC_DATA
                                        ,   UA1.BANK_COMMUNICATION AS UA1_BANK_COMMUNICATION
                                        ,   U2.USER_ID AS U2_USER_ID
                                        ,   UA2.USER_ID AS UA2_USER_ID
                                        ,   UA2.CUSTOMER_ID AS UA2_CUSTOMER_ID
                                        ,   UA2.ENTITY AS UA2_ENTITY
                                        ,   UA2.SIGNATURE_LEVEL AS UA2_SIGNATURE_LEVEL
                                        ,   UA2.INQUIRY AS UA2_INQUIRY
                                        ,   UA2.TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION AS UA2_TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION
                                        ,   UA2.IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS AS UA2_IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                        ,   UA2.IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS AS UA2_IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                        ,   UA2.CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR AS UA2_CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR
                                        ,   UA2.IS_AUDIT AS UA2_IS_AUDIT
                                        ,   UA2.INTERNAL_LIMIT AS UA2_INTERNAL_LIMIT
                                        ,   UA2.PURGE AS UA2_PURGE
                                        ,   UA2.STATIC_DATA AS UA2_STATIC_DATA
                                        ,   UA2.BANK_COMMUNICATION AS UA2_BANK_COMMUNICATION
                                    FROM        T_CUSTOMER_PROFILE_BASE C
                                    JOIN        T_USER_PROFILE_BASE U1          ON  C.ENTITY                = U1.ENTITY    
                                                                                AND C.CUSTOMER_ID           = U1.DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ID
                                    JOIN        T_USER_PROFILE_BASE U2          ON  C.ENTITY                = U2.ENTITY
                                                                                AND C.CUSTOMER_ID           = U2.DEFAULT_CUSTOMER_ID
                                    JOIN        T_USER_AUTHORIZATION_BASE UA1   ON  C.ENTITY                = UA1.ENTITY
                                                                                AND C.CUSTOMER_ID           = UA1.CUSTOMER_ID
                                                                                AND U1.USER_ID              = UA1.USER_ID    
                                    LEFT JOIN   T_USER_AUTHORIZATION_BASE UA2   ON  C.ENTITY                = UA2.ENTITY
                                                                                AND C.CUSTOMER_ID           = UA2.CUSTOMER_ID
                                                                                AND U2.USER_ID              = UA2.USER_ID    
                                    WHERE       C.ENTITY        IN ('030')                                                                                                               
                                    AND         C.CUSTOMER_ID   IN (:CustomerID)
                                    AND         U1.USER_ID      IN (:FromUserID)
                                    AND         U2.USER_ID      IN (SELECT IDS.ToUserID FROM XMLTABLE('/ToUserIDs/ToUserID' PASSING XMLTYPE (:ToUserIDsElement) COLUMNS ToUserID VARCHAR(100) PATH '/ToUserID/.') IDS)
                                )   SRC
                                ON (    
                                                SRC.UA1_ENTITY      = TGT.ENTITY
                                            AND SRC.UA1_CUSTOMER_ID = TGT.CUSTOMER_ID
                                            AND SRC.U2_USER_ID      = TGT.USER_ID
                                ) 
                                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET    TGT.SIGNATURE_LEVEL                 =   SRC.UA1_SIGNATURE_LEVEL
                                                            ,   TGT.INQUIRY                         =   SRC.UA1_INQUIRY
                                                            ,   TGT.TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION       =   SRC.UA1_TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION
                                                            ,   TGT.IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS  =   SRC.UA1_IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   TGT.IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS  =   SRC.UA1_IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   TGT.CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR             =   SRC.UA1_CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR
                                                            ,   TGT.IS_AUDIT                        =   SRC.UA1_IS_AUDIT
                                                            ,   TGT.INTERNAL_LIMIT                  =   SRC.UA1_INTERNAL_LIMIT
                                                            ,   TGT.PURGE                           =   SRC.UA1_PURGE
                                                            ,   TGT.STATIC_DATA                     =   SRC.UA1_STATIC_DATA
                                                            ,   TGT.BANK_COMMUNICATION              =   SRC.UA1_BANK_COMMUNICATION
                                WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT(   ENTITY
                                                            ,   USER_ID
                                                            ,   CUSTOMER_ID
                                                            ,   SIGNATURE_LEVEL
                                                            ,   INQUIRY
                                                            ,   TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION
                                                            ,   IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR
                                                            ,   IS_AUDIT
                                                            ,   INTERNAL_LIMIT
                                                            ,   PURGE
                                                            ,   STATIC_DATA
                                                            ,   BANK_COMMUNICATION
                                                            )
                                                      VALUES(   SRC.UA1_ENTITY
                                                            ,   SRC.U2_USER_ID
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_CUSTOMER_ID
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_SIGNATURE_LEVEL
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_INQUIRY
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_TRANSACTION_AUTHORIZATION
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_IS_MANAGE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_IS_CREATE_INTERNAL_DEPARTMENTS
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_CUSTOMER_SUPERVISOR
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_IS_AUDIT
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_INTERNAL_LIMIT
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_PURGE
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_STATIC_DATA
                                                            ,   SRC.UA1_BANK_COMMUNICATION
                                                            )";
                using (oracleDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())
                {
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = new OracleCommand(commandText, oracleConnection);
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Transaction = oracleTransaction;
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":CustomerID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = CustomerID;
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":FromUserID", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = FromUserID;
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":ToUserIDsElement", OracleDbType.NVarchar2)).Value = ToUserIDsElement.ToString();
                    oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                oracleTransaction.Commit();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        oracleTransaction.Rollback();
        MessageBox.Show($"{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name} : {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name} : {e1.Message}");
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oracleConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            oracleTransaction.Dispose();
            oracleConnection.Close();
            oracleDataAdapter.UpdateCommand.Dispose();
            oracleDataAdapter.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is most likely more of an Oracle Question than a .NET one. Check your database logs for the reason the statement hangs.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, so my code is good?

Comment: I haven't checked your database query of course, but the C# code should work - even if a little messy, non-asynchronous and inelegant 

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, I am happy to learn where I can to make it less messy and more elegant..

Comment: 1. Go Async if you can, starting with OpenAsync the connection. 2. The query could be a constant. 3. The finally block is redundant if you have the proper using statements in place.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold, I will see if I can find information on Async.  Thanks for the pointers.

(The DBA saw there was a session that got stuck so now the issue is resolved)

Comment: Great! Good luck.

Comment: Not sure why you need a data adapter, you can just the command object. Probably the query is getting stuck due to poor performance, but without knowing what indexes etc you have it's hard to say.

Comment: @Charlieface, how do I fill my DataTable without a DataAdapter?

Comment: If you were filling a datatable you could do `using (var command = new OracleCommand(commandText, connection)) using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) datatable.Load(reader);`. But you are not, so you can just do `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` This won't fix your issue, but it's neater